# Using Years unit interval in Swift Foundation Measurements framework

Tags: swift, xcode, foundation, units-of-measurement, measurement

how can I display date iterval in years (or years + months) using Foundation’s Measurements()? I’ve made it to display interval but biggest unit I’ve found it hours … and it is not valid for me (display with beautiful localisation 87600 hours for 10y interval)

how to fix this?

my code:

```
// MODEL part
var yearsLived: Measurement<UnitDuration>? {
    if let hours = birthDate?.getInterval(toDate: deathDate, component: .hour) {
        let hours = Measurement(value: Double(hours), unit: UnitDuration.hours)
        return hours
    }
    return nil
}

// VC PART:
if let yearsLived = person?.yearsLived {
    let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
    formatter.unitStyle = .long
    formatter.unitOptions = [.naturalScale]

    yearsLivedLabel.text = formatter.string(from: yearsLived)
}
```

Comment: Measurement is not how you display time intervals.

Comment: so what it is Unit Duration else like time interval?

from documentation:

Duration
Duration is a quantity of time. The SI unit for time is the second (sec), which is defined in terms of the radioactivity of a cesium-133 atom. Duration is also commonly expressed in terms of minutes (min) and hours (hr).

years / months / days is just another time interval expression

Comment: It also say in the documentation to use DateComponents for years, months, weeks and days.

Comment: I look for solution not argueing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I display date iterval in years (or years + months) using Foundation’s Measurements

You don't. You use [DateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter).

Comment: thank you @matt that worked. I'm sorry about little misunderstanding whether to use Measurements or DateComponents for proper localization strings. Now it works perfectly with your help